# Наголос: прИстань чи пристАнь?

Tags: наголос

[СУМ:](http://sum.in.ua/s/prystanj) наголос на А.

[Словники від УЛІФ:](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C) наголос на И.

Хто правий? Чи є такий ресурс, де можна точно дізнатися наголос, і бути впевненим, що саме цей ресурс надає правдиву інформацію? З чим повʼязані ці невідповідності?

Comment: https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=wharf&from_lang=en&to_lang=uk ось цим я трохи більше довіряю, але все одно - вони не остання інстанція.

Comment: @Follower ви праві щодо назви поселення, але тепер ви додали взагалі дієслово. Я ж казав про іменник, що видно з посилання на СУМ.

Comment: @Follower дякую, тоді, виходить, відпадає і перше запитання.

Comment: @Follower скажіть, будь ласка, а як ви знайшли ту сторінку, де є всі ці іменники і прикметники? Я не вмію так на УЛІФ шукати. Думаю, видалю питання, тільки хотів би спочатку дізнатися, як ви шукаєте.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62756/discussion-between-p-vovk-and-follower).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Пр**и**стань

Дещо комедійна ситуація — виявляється, що це звичайна технічна помилка на боці сайту СУМ, бо [сканування](http://sum.in.ua/p/8/38/2) дає інший наголос, який збігається зі словником з УЛІФ:
[image]